# SQLite tool with possiblity to insert entries between existing entries in a table

Tags: sqlite

I currently use the DB browser for SQLite (https://sqlitebrowser.org/) as my SQLite tool. However in this tool I can't insert any new entries between two exisiting entries. Whenenver I click on insert entries, the new entry is always inserted at the very end of the table. As I would like to have an alphabetic ordering of my entries (for a small dictionary) I would like to ask you whether you know a SQLite tool that is capable of doing this? So ideally the tool should be able to sort all entries automatically. If this is not possible then at least the it should be possible to insert new entries between 2 existing entries such I can do the alphabetic sorting on my own.

Do you know a tool that can do that?

Comment: There is no such thing as first, last or in between for the rows of a table. What you need is a SELECT query with an ORDER BY clause. Google it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer forpas. I am not talking about inserting an entry into the database via code (e.g. Java) but just manually I want to insert entries in the database by just typing them into the database. And here I would like to insert them between entries such that I have a better overview about the database table.

Comment: The overview of the table can be done anyway you want it by writing a SELECT query with an ORDER BY clause. My previous comment was not about programming languages but about how things work in sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort records, don't need to rearrange the things in the database.
There is no direct method to insert between records.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rakesh. I am not talking about inserting a database via code (e.g. Java) but just manually I want to insert entries in the database by just typing them into the database. And here I would like to insert them between entries such that I have a better overview about the database.

Comment: Oh! Then do one thing. Export data as csv, sort things in excel and open again in DB browser. Excel has those features to edit data.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your answer. Basically your suggested approach works. However, as I have to change the data in the database manually quite often, I am wondering whether there is a SQLite-tool that supports something like this natively. The  DB browser for SQLite (https://sqlitebrowser.org/) does not do it. It is a fairly simple tool and does not have many functions. Do you know more advanced SQLite tools? Because I assume that they could do that.

Comment: Yes, DB browser doesn't have that functionality because not needed. Excel is the tool to work with data. But DB browser just shows data. I also checked robo3t db viewer it also doesn't have that functionality. I don't know any other tools, sorry.

Comment: Okay thanks for your comments and answers Rakesh. I upvoted your answer.